# Partitioning a linked list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to solve this algorithmic problem based on linked list data structure. The question is as follows:

**Given a linked list and a value x, partition it such that all nodes less than x come before nodes greater than or equal to x.
You should preserve the original relative order of the nodes in each of the two partitions.**

**For example,**

**Given 1->4->3->2->5->2 and x = 3,
return 1->2->2->4->3->5.**

My solution to the problem is:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    public ListNode partition(ListNode head, int x) {
        if(head == null) return null;
        ListNode headNode = new ListNode(-1);
        headNode.next = head;

        ListNode tail = head;
        while(tail.next!=null){
            tail = tail.next;
        }
        ListNode actualTail = tail;
        ListNode current = headNode;
        while(current!=actualTail && current.next!=actualTail){
            if(current.next.val >= x && current.next!=tail){
                System.out.println("Moving "+current.next.val+" to end of list, ahead of "+tail.val);
                ListNode temp = current.next;
                current.next = current.next.next;
                tail.next = temp;
                tail = tail.next;
                tail.next = null;
            }else{
                current = current.next;    
            }

        }
        return headNode.next;
    }
}
```

While some test cases work fine with this code such as the one mentioned above, there are a set of test cases that fail, in that I am unable to maintain the original relative ordering of the nodes in the list.

For example: 
list = [1->2]
x = 0

My result: 
[2,1]

Expected:
[1,2]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: all nodes less than x come before nodes greater than or equal to x . Also preserve the original relative order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do it in a simpler way:

- Keep 2 lists, one for lower nodes and other for greater nodes.
- Iterate the list adding the nodes to the corresponding list.
- Concatenate the lower list with greater list

Something like this:

```
public ListNode Partition(ListNode head, int x)
{
    ListNode lowerHead = null, lowerTail = null;              //Head and Tail of lower list
    ListNode greaterHead = null, greaterTail = null;          //Head and Tail of greater list

    ListNode current = head;

    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current.val < x)
        {
            if (lowerHead == null) lowerHead = current;      //If is the first node in the list
            if (lowerTail == null) lowerTail = current;      //set the head an tail to the same value
            else lowerTail = lowerTail.next = current;       //Otherwise, add the node and update the tail
        }
        else
        {
            if (greaterHead == null) greaterHead = current;  //If is the first node in the list
            if (greaterTail == null) greaterTail = current;  //set the head an tail to the same value
            else greaterTail = greaterTail.next = current;   //Otherwise, add the node and update the tail
        }

        current = current.next;
    }

    if (greaterHead != null)
        greaterTail.next = null;

    if (lowerHead == null) return greaterHead;
    else
    {
        lowerTail.next = greaterHead;
        return lowerHead;
    }
}
```

Order is preserved since nodes are added as they appear in the original list

Comment: as an additional requirement, what if we have to do it in-place. That's what I was trying to do in my approach.

Comment: Actually, in-place is a little confusing here since only `next` references are changed (there is not a list object, only nodes interconnected)

Answer (score 2):

> It can be done in place, in **O(N)** time **O(1)** space. Just keep
>   track of the immediate preceding node, before the first node, that is
>   greater than or equal to the X.
>
> This node acts as the boundary between the nodes that are less than X
>   and nodes that are greater than or equal to X.
>
> Refer the code along with inline comments.

```
    class Solution {
    public ListNode partition(ListNode head, int x) {
        // Assume that list has at least one instance of X and x = 3

        ListNode dummy = new ListNode(-1);
        dummy.next = head;
        ListNode prev = dummy;
        ListNode curr = head;

        // Keeps track of the preceding node, before the first value greater than or equal to x.
        ListNode large = null;
        // Tracks weather the first node greater than or equal to x has been found.
        boolean isFirstLargeFound = false;

        while(curr != null) {
            if (curr.val >= x) {
                if (!isFirstLargeFound) {
                    large = prev;
                    isFirstLargeFound = true;    
                }
            } else if (isFirstLargeFound) {
                // If the current value is less than x and the first larger value has
                // been found, we need to swap the nodes.
                //
                // Consider the example: 1->4->0->3->2->5, the curr node is at value 0.
                // At this point of time the first larger value i.e. 4 has been already
                // found, hence we have to move the Node with value 0 to a place before 
                // the node with value 4.
                //
                // Before: 1->4->0->3->2->5
                // After: 1->0->4->3->2->5
                ListNode temp = large.next;
                prev.next = curr.next;
                large.next = curr;
                // Ensures that the first element that is >=X, is always next of large node.
                curr.next = temp;
                large = large.next;
            }

            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return dummy.next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in Python and works fine.

```
current = runner = ll.head
while runner:
    if runner.value < part:
        temp = current.value
        current.value = runner.value
        runner.value = temp

        current = current.next
        runner = runner.next
    else:
        runner = runner.next
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an bit old thread, I hope this will be useful for someone.

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def insert_node(self, val):
        new_node = ListNode(val)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.tail = new_node
        else:
            self.tail.next = new_node
            self.tail = new_node

class Solution:
    def partition(self, head: ListNode, x: int) -> ListNode:
        if head is None or head.next is None:
            return head
        else:
            tmp = head
            low = LinkedList()
            high = LinkedList()
            while tmp is not None:
                if tmp.val < x:                    
                    low.insert_node(tmp.val)
                else:
                    high.insert_node(tmp.val)
                tmp = tmp.next
            if low.head is not None:
                tail = low.head
                while tail.next is not None:
                    tail = tail.next
                tail.next = high.head
                output = low.head
            else:
                output = high.head
            return output
```