# What is meant by 'Partitioning a linked list'?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Can someone explain to me what exactly this question is asking? I am confused about this question as it says values less than x (=3) should be before 3, but then why 4 is appearing before 3 as it is >=3? Same doubt follows the second example as well as why 10 is before 5.

> Given a linked list and a value x, partition it such that all nodes less than x come before nodes greater than or equal to x. You should preserve the original relative order of the nodes in each of the two partitions. If x is contained within the list, the values of x only need to be after the elements less than x.The partition element x can appear anywhere in the "right partition".
>
> For example,

```
> Given 1->4->3->2->5->2 and x = 3, return 1->2->2->4->3->5.
> Given 3->5->8->5->10->2->1 and x = 5 return 3->1->2->10->5->5->8
```

Comment: sounds like a badly written question!  in the question (as stated) I don't see why those 2s move while the 4 stays where it is (relative to the 3)

Comment: First off, it is not your fault, the question could be worded a lot better. However, the example makes it clear if you just look at it and get the gist of it. The goal is this. Rewriting as groups: [1, 4] - [3] - [2, 5, 2]. Your aim is to ensure nothing on the right of 3 is smaller than it. so, the culprit are the two 2s. However, you do NOT need to ensure that values greater than 3 move over from left to right. At that point, you need to ensure the left and right groups are sorted as long as the original order is retained. sounds weird to me but oh well.

Comment: seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37076648/1358308

Comment: @Paritosh so the question gives another example: 

I/P : 3 5 8 5 10 2 1 

O/P: 3 1 2 10 5 5 8

x = 5

which doesnt satisfy your logic. 


Sam : The approach was discussed in this article which didnt clarify my doubt.

Comment: wow, uh... i mean, this just seems like a terribly explained question. I can't find a good reason to get that example working.

Comment: The question is fine, but the second example seems like it's incorrect. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partitioning-a-linked-list-around-a-given-value-and-keeping-the-original-order/.

Comment: Wait, that second example is clearly no good. The problem statement says you're supposed to preserve the order of the values in the two parts of the partition, but it's reordering both sides. If the result was `3->2->1->5->8->5->10` it would make sense to me.

Comment: seems to come from: https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-list/ and there are questions here for at least a couple of years…

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning a linked list with respect to x partitions the list into 3 groups:

```
Group1: values less than x
Group2: values equal to x
Group3: values more than x
```

Partitioning can also be done into 2 groups (thats is the instruction in the question):

```
Group1: values less than x
Group2: values greater or equal to x
```

But the order remains unchanged within the group.

In your example: 1->4->3->2->5->2,

Partitioning into 3 groups for x=3 should produce: 1->2->2->3->4->5

Partitioning into 2 groups for x=3 should produce: 1->2->2->4->3->5

Here 4 comes before 3 since it preserves the original order in Group 2.

Comment: Partitioning can be two-way, rather than three way. That is, you can lump values equal to the pivot into one side or the other. That seems to be what the questioner's problem statement was asking for, and it would make their first example make perfect sense (the two halves of the partition would be `1, 2, 2` and `4, 3, 5`). The second example doesn't make any sense though, as a bunch of the values in each half are out of order (the problem statement says original relative order is supposed to be preserved in each piece).

Comment: Oh, I see, I will update the answer using 2 groups, since that is what the questioner meant.

Comment: well , we can divide the thing into two groups which is not an issue, my question mainly tries to  demystify the logic of the question which seems to be vague. Maybe the question is worded wrongly, because I am not able to make sense of the second example in any of the ways.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your confusion has to do with how you handle items in the list that are equal to `x`, the pivot number. The key thing to note is this part of the instructions:

> all nodes less than x come before nodes greater than or equal to x

You're just supposed to split the list into two parts: Those "less than `x`" and those "greater than or equal to `x`". Any values equal to `x` are in the second category, and not treated differently than any others.

You seem to have instinctively been wanting to do a three-way partition, where the values equal to `x` are not included in either of the two main parts of the list. Instead, all values equal to `x` would get stuck in the middle, in between the "less than `x`" values and the "greater than `x`" values.

A three-way partition is often more efficient than a two-way partition, but it's not what your problem is asking for. That's why you're being told you're giving the wrong answer for some of the inputs.

Note that this still doesn't make any sense of the second example you've given. A two-way stable partition of `3->5->8->5->10->2->1` on pivot value `5` should give: `3->2->1->5->8->5->10`, not the output you describe, which reorders both sides of the list for no obvious reason.